# Dynamically added textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a table I'd like to make editable line by line, user clicks on a cell containing text and it changes to text area.

Textarea adds fine, but is totally non-functional.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na7sZ/)

Or code of what I'm trying to do?

```
<div id="click"></div>

#click {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

$(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $(this).html("<textarea></textarea>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `focus` event after you add the `textarea`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#click').click(function () {
       $(this).html("<textarea></textarea>").find("textarea").focus();
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/na7sZ/2/

You could also do it this way :

```
$('#click').click(function () {
        var textarea = $('<textarea/>');
        $(this).html(textarea);
        textarea.focus();
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/na7sZ/5/

Comment: Will be better to create jquery object : var textarea = $('<textarea/>'), after that $(this).append(textarea); textarea.focus();

Answer (score 1):

That is because your textarea is inside the `click` div, so a click on the textarea is also a click on the div, wich remove/create a new textarea.

Add this to you code :

```
$('#click').on('click', 'textarea', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

It will stop the event from bubbling and not recreate a textarea.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/na7sZ/4/

Comment: i think function required variable e ?